# Linking Google Analytics 360 to Big Query, permissions issue

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have linked GA360 to Big Query. I do have a service account added to GCP as per documentation. The account I used has Project Owner permissions as required to link to said project.

Can I remove the Project Owner permissions from the GCP account once the link has been established in GA360? I do not want that account to have such a high access level to the project.

I did run a test on a small scale and it worked but I am not willing to risk a transfer failure on all of the data in production.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove the permissions from the account you used to link GA360 to BQ.

The permission is only required for the time of setting this up. 
It is not being checked whether the account which set up a connection is still active or has the same rights.

We have had multiple views linked by different accounts, of which most are not in the team anymore and therefore do not have "owner" rights anymore. The exports still work though (which makes sense, given that a company might keep using GA and the exports but part ways with the internal/external employee who sat it up).